# How to stream and convert live video into mp-4. How to use FFMPEG?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am developing iphone application which requires live video stream (Flash or any other) to be run on iphone. Can anybody help me to stream live video using HTTPLiveStreaming. And i want to use FFMPEG converter for converting video into mp4. Is there any step by step documentation to use ffmpeg into iphone sdk?

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For live streams, Apple provides a [free tool](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW3) to make media segment files and playlists from live MPEG-2 transport streams carrying H.264 video, AAC audio, or MP3 audio. There are a number of hardware and software encoders that can create MPEG-2 transport streams carrying MPEG-4 video and AAC audio in real time.

There is no reason to use a huge FFMPEG library. If you send live video to iOS device then this video should be compatible with iOS (and most likely it will already be such as MP4). You just send this video stream to media player(MPMoviePlayerController) and all will works fine. See also [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-DontLinkElementID_39)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apple's HTTPLiveStreaming protocol strict with h.264/MPEG-4 videos only. My requirement is to play all type of video (Flash and other).

Comment: You cann't play all types of video. If you would like to send a lot of media bytes to your app, then you have to used HTTP Live Streaming, in other case app will be rejected.

Comment: Could i get flash video stream with HTTPLiveStreaming and then convert it into mp4?

Comment: This task you need to perform on server side and after this send mp4 to iOS devices